# Bokeh Python; Use Callback on ColumnDataSource to change Stacked Bar Chart with Select Widget

Tags: javascript, python, callback, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to use a java script callback with bokeh(python) to change a stacked bar chart when given a select widget value. I am using the rect glyphs to build the stacked bar chart.  Each bar is an age group and my widget should select one age group to display.  All I need to do is tell the chart to stop rendering the other rect glyphs and change the y value of the one age group to equal its height (thus making it a simple bar chart).

I have all my data in arrays, but then I turn it into lists in order to pass it to the callback. My java script alert tells me that my for statement works and it is reading the y values fine.  The logic of my callback may be funky/incorrect, but I'm more worried about the fact that the glyphs don't change at all in response to the callback.  Maybe it's the way I'm pushing the data in the callback? Thanks!!

```
from bokeh.models import  Callback, ColumnDataSource, Rect, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, VBox, gridplot, HBox
import pandas as pd


#Color Dictionary
redcolor5 = {u'All ages': "#720017", u'70+ years': "#bd0026", u'50-69 years':  "#f03b20", u'15-49 years': "#fd8d3c", u'Under 5 years': "#f4cc63", u'gridline': '#b2ada6', u'background': '#e3e0db', u'axis' : '#aba9a7'}

#Just a sample of my data
country_both = ['China', 'India', 'United States', 'Russia', 'Japan', 'Indonesia', 'Germany', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Brazil']
ages_gen = ['Under 5 years', '15-49 years', '50-69 years', '70+ years', 'All ages', 'Age-standardized']

height70yr = [919470, 421922, 321125, 193960, 148946, 107822, 97529, 90198, 81107, 76782]
height50to69 = [640496, 626995, 182338, 195472, 40422, 109242, 44161, 33333, 24964, 64429]
height15to49 = [126094, 139420, 26159, 43239, 5480, 39040, 6829, 4163, 3571, 16152]
heightUnder5 = [10210, 43338, 82, 714, 41, 5255, 0, 26, 0, 1201]

frame = pd.DataFrame({"arBoth_70yr_Cnty": height70yr, "arBoth_5069yr_Cnty": height50to69, "arBoth_1549yr_Cnty": height15to49, "arBoth_5yr_Cnty": heightUnder5})
arBoth_70yr_Cnty = frame['arBoth_70yr_Cnty'] 
arBoth_5069yr_Cnty = frame['arBoth_5069yr_Cnty']
arBoth_1549yr_Cnty = frame['arBoth_1549yr_Cnty']
arBoth_5yr_Cnty = frame['arBoth_5yr_Cnty']

#Y Values for Stacked bar chart
yUnder5 = (arBoth_5yr_Cnty/2).tolist()
y15to49 = (arBoth_5yr_Cnty+arBoth_1549yr_Cnty/2).tolist()
y50to69 = (arBoth_5yr_Cnty+arBoth_1549yr_Cnty+arBoth_5069yr_Cnty/2).tolist()
y70yr = (arBoth_5yr_Cnty+arBoth_1549yr_Cnty+arBoth_5069yr_Cnty+arBoth_70yr_Cnty/2).tolist()


output_file('UW_TobaccoDeath.html')

#Figure for Stacked bar chart
p1 = figure(title="Top Countries with Death Due to Tobacco by Age", 
            x_range=country_both, y_range=[0, max(arBoth_5yr_Cnty+arBoth_1549yr_Cnty+arBoth_5069yr_Cnty+arBoth_70yr_Cnty)],
            background_fill=redcolor5['background'], 
            plot_width=700, plot_height = 400,
            outline_line_color= None)


#source for callback
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=country_both, yUnder5 = yUnder5, heightUnder5 = heightUnder5, y15to49 = y15to49, height15to49 = height15to49, y50to69 = y50to69, height50to69 = height50to69, y70yr=y70yr, height70yr = height70yr))

#Use rect glyphs for stached bars
p1.rect(x ='x', y ='yUnder5', width =.8, height = 'heightUnder5', source = source1, color=redcolor5['Under 5 years'], alpha=0.8, name = "Under 5")
p1.rect(x = 'x', y ='y15to49', width = .8, height ='height15to49', source = source1, color=redcolor5['15-49 years'], alpha=0.8, name = "15 to 49")
p1.rect(x = 'x', y ='y50to69', width = .8, height ='height50to69', source = source1, color=redcolor5['50-69 years'], alpha = .8, name = "50 to 69")
p1.rect(x = 'x', y ='y70yr', width = .8, height ='height70yr', source = source1, color=redcolor5['70+ years'], alpha = .8, name = "70+ yrs")


#Java script Callbacks for age  
#I want this to recognize the 70+ year old drop down selection 
#and change the plot so that the height of the glyph is the same as the y value and the 70 year old glyph is the only one that displays
Callback_Age = Callback(args=dict(source1 = source1), code="""
        var f = cb_obj.get('value');
        var data = source1.get('data');
        var x = data['x'];

        if (f == '70+ years') {
            var y = 0;
            var height = data['height70yr'];
            alert(height);
            }

        data['x'].push(x);
        data['y'].push(y);
        data['height'].push(height);
        source1.trigger('change');

    """)

#Use the Select widget
dropdown_age = Select(title="Ages:", value=ages_gen[4], options= ages_gen,  callback = Callback_Age)

#Display data
filters = VBox(dropdown_age)
tot =  HBox(filters, gridplot([[p1]]))
show(tot)
```

Answer (score 3):

thanks for researching tobacco-related casualties!

My way of doing what you want is to use 4 sources (1 per age group), and then manually change them depending on age group selected. If 15-49 age group is selected, associated source y is centered down (to height / 0), and height of all others is set to 0. I have done the 'all age' group, but not 'age standardized'. And I have not tried to resize figure to see better the Under 5 years group either.
Oh, and I also swapped to numpy arrays. It is just a convenience thing, you can keep on with Python lists and Panda frames if you prefer.

Ask me if you have any further question,
Thierry

```
from bokeh.models import  Callback, ColumnDataSource, Rect, Select,CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show,  gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets.layouts import VBox,HBox
import numpy as np


#Color Dictionary
redcolor5 = {u'All ages': "#720017", u'70+ years': "#bd0026", u'50-69 years':  "#f03b20", u'15-49 years': "#fd8d3c", u'Under 5 years': "#f4cc63", u'gridline': '#b2ada6', u'background': '#e3e0db', u'axis' : '#aba9a7'}

#Just a sample of my data
country_both = ['China', 'India', 'United States', 'Russia', 'Japan', 'Indonesia', 'Germany', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Brazil']
ages_gen = ['Under 5 years', '15-49 years', '50-69 years', '70+ years', 'All ages', 'Age-standardized']

height70yr = np.array([919470, 421922, 321125, 193960, 148946, 107822, 97529, 90198, 81107, 76782])
height50to69 = np.array([640496, 626995, 182338, 195472, 40422, 109242, 44161, 33333, 24964, 64429])
height15to49 = np.array([126094, 139420, 26159, 43239, 5480, 39040, 6829, 4163, 3571, 16152])
heightUnder5 = np.array([10210, 43338, 82, 714, 41, 5255, 0, 26, 0, 1201])
zeros = np.zeros(len(country_both))


#Y Values for Stacked bar chart
yUnder5 = heightUnder5 / 2.0
y15to49 = yUnder5 + height15to49/2.0
y50to69 = y15to49 + height50to69/2.0
y70yr = y50to69 + height70yr/2.0


output_file('UW_TobaccoDeath.html')

#Figure for Stacked bar chart
p1 = figure(title="Top Countries with Death Due to Tobacco by Age", 
            x_range=country_both, y_range=[0, np.amax([y70yr+height70yr])],
            background_fill=redcolor5['background'], 
            plot_width=700, plot_height = 600,
            outline_line_color= None)


#source for callback
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=country_both, y = yUnder5, y_full = yUnder5, height = heightUnder5, height_full = heightUnder5 ,height_zeros = zeros, y_zeros = heightUnder5 / 2.0))
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=country_both, y = y15to49, y_full = y15to49, height = height15to49, height_full = height15to49,height_zeros = zeros, y_zeros = height15to49 / 2.0))
source3 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=country_both, y = y50to69, y_full = y50to69, height = height50to69, height_full = height50to69,height_zeros = zeros , y_zeros = height50to69 / 2.0))
source4 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=country_both, y = y70yr, y_full = y70yr, height = height70yr, height_full = height70yr,height_zeros = zeros, y_zeros =  height70yr / 2.0))

#Use rect glyphs for stached bars
p1.rect(x ='x', y ='y', width =.8, height = 'height', source = source1, color=redcolor5['Under 5 years'], alpha=0.8, name = "Under 5")
p1.rect(x = 'x', y ='y', width = .8, height ='height', source = source2, color=redcolor5['15-49 years'], alpha=0.8, name = "15 to 49")
p1.rect(x = 'x', y ='y', width = .8, height ='height', source = source3, color=redcolor5['50-69 years'], alpha = .8, name = "50 to 69")
p1.rect(x = 'x', y ='y', width = .8, height ='height', source = source4, color=redcolor5['70+ years'], alpha = .8, name = "70+ yrs")

#Java script Callbacks for age  
#I want this to recognize the 70+ year old drop down selection 
#and change the plot so that the height of the glyph is the same as the y value and the 70 year old glyph is the only one that displays
Callback_Age = CustomJS(args={'source1': source1,'source2': source2,'source3': source3,'source4': source4}, code="""
        var f = cb_obj.get('value');
        var data1 = source1.get('data');
        var data2 = source2.get('data');
        var data3 = source3.get('data');
        var data4 = source4.get('data');
        if (f == 'Under 5 years') {
            data3['height'] = data3['height_zeros'];
            data2['height'] = data2['height_zeros'];
            data4['height'] = data4['height_zeros'];
            data1['y'] = data1['y_zeros'];
            data1['height'] = data1['height_full'];
            source1.trigger('change');
            source2.trigger('change');
            source3.trigger('change');
            source4.trigger('change');
            }
        if (f == '15-49 years') {
            data1['height'] = data1['height_zeros'];
            data3['height'] = data3['height_zeros'];
            data4['height'] = data4['height_zeros'];
            data2['y'] = data2['y_zeros'];
            data2['height'] = data2['height_full'];
            source1.trigger('change');
            source2.trigger('change');
            source3.trigger('change');
            source4.trigger('change');
            }

        if (f == '50-69 years') {
            data1['height'] = data1['height_zeros'];
            data2['height'] = data2['height_zeros'];
            data4['height'] = data4['height_zeros'];
            data3['y'] = data3['y_zeros'];
            data3['height'] = data3['height_full'];
            console.log('data3',data3)
            source1.trigger('change');
            source2.trigger('change');
            source3.trigger('change');
            source4.trigger('change');
            }
        if (f == '70+ years') {
            data1['height'] = data1['height_zeros'];
            data2['height'] = data2['height_zeros'];
            data3['height'] = data3['height_zeros'];
            data4['y'] = data4['y_zeros'];
            data4['height'] = data4['height_full'];
            source1.trigger('change');
            source2.trigger('change');
            source3.trigger('change');
            source4.trigger('change');
            }
        if (f == 'All ages') {
            data1['height'] = data1['height_full'];
            data1['y'] = data1['y_full'];
            data2['height'] = data2['height_full'];
            data2['y'] = data2['y_full'];
            data3['height'] = data3['height_full'];
            data3['y'] = data3['y_full'];
            data4['height'] = data4['height_full'];
            data4['y'] = data4['y_full'];
            source1.trigger('change');
            source2.trigger('change');
            source3.trigger('change');
            source4.trigger('change');
            }



    """)
#Use the Select widget
dropdown_age = Select(title="Ages:", value=ages_gen[4], options= ages_gen,  callback = Callback_Age)

#Display data
filters = VBox(dropdown_age)
tot =  HBox(filters, gridplot([[p1]]))
show(tot)
```

Comment: Create use of CustomJS. One question. COULD you add a legend for the Colors (age group)?

Comment: Is it possible to pass a list of sources as argument for the callback function? What if there are 20 different sources?